# Repeating color patter using css nth-child pseudo code

Tags: html, css

I have build a sample page as below. But the box colors are assigned by selecting specific boxes.

```css
body, *{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container{
  width:200px;
  margin:0px auto;
}
.box{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  float:left;
}
.box:nth-child(1){
  background-color:red;
}
.box:nth-child(2){
  background-color:green;
}
.box:nth-child(3){
  background-color:green;
}
.box:nth-child(4){
  background-color:red;
}
.box:nth-child(5){
  background-color:red;
}
.box:nth-child(6){
  background-color:green;
}
.box:nth-child(7){
  background-color:green;
}
.box:nth-child(8){
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

I want to change it so that whenever new boxes added or any box delete, the red-green pattern do not break. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following the pattern the `4n` and `4n+1` `.box` children are red, while `4n+2` and `4n+3` `.box` children are green

```css
body, *{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container{
  width:200px;
  margin:0px auto;
}
.box{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  float:left;
}

.box:nth-child(4n), 
.box:nth-child(4n + 1) {
  background-color:red;
}

.box:nth-child(4n + 2), 
.box:nth-child(4n + 3) {
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

On modern browser you could also grouping the `:nth-child` pseudoclasses, by using the new `:is` pseudoclass

```
.box:is(:nth-child(4n), :nth-child(4n + 1)) {
  background-color:red;
}

.box:is(:nth-child(4n + 2), :nth-child(4n + 3)) {
  background-color:green;
}
```

And if you're looking for a shorter code just assign by default a `green` background to all the `.box` elements, then change it to `red` only on `4n` and `4n+1` elements.

```
.box {
  background-color:green;
}

.box:nth-child(4n), 
.box:nth-child(4n + 1) {
  background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: Damn, that was quick. Thank You :)
I get it now, so its not 2 box pattern but 4 box pattern. I was trying it with 2n and 2n+1 on my system and it was not working. :)

Comment: it's `4n` because the pattern repeat itself after 4 box elements: `rggr/rggr/...`

Comment: For a simple background change like that, you could also ditch the second selector and add a default color to `.box`, leaving you with `.box:nth-child(4n), 
.box:nth-child(4n + 1)` only.

Answer (score 0):

You can pair your selector with `+ *` selector

```css
body,
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  background-color: blue;
}

.box:nth-child(4n+4),
.box:nth-child(4n+4)+* {
  background-color: blue;
}

.box:nth-child(4n+2),
.box:nth-child(4n+2)+* {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
  <div class="box">5</div>
  <div class="box">6</div>
  <div class="box">7</div>
</div>
```